# Defining convexity for a function $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ where $M\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ is a convex set

Tags: real-analysis

The question from Pugh is as follows:

"Formulate a definition of convexity for function $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ where $M\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ is a convex set."

where the hint is to start from the case $m=2$.

We have that $\forall x,y\in M$, we have $sx+ty\in M$ where $s+t=1$ and $0\leq s,t\leq 1$ by $M$ being a convex set. I am currently struggling to understand how $M$ being a convex set would help us formulate the definition of convexity for function $f$.

We were given in the question that $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function if $\forall x,y\in (a,b)$ and all $s,t\in[0,1]$ with $s+t=1$, we have $f(sx+ty)\leq sf(x)+tf(y)$.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Hint: Suppose that $M=R^m$. Could you repeat the definition of convexity of functions from the 1-dimensional case in this setting?

Comment: _" I am currently struggling to understand how $M$ being a convex set would help us formulate the definition of convexity for function"_ - Try to define a convex function on a non-convex set and then look carefully if everything is fine or if something is missing. Start with $m=1$ and test all definitions of convexity you know.